# I am getting (500) Internal Server Error while loading url on XMLDocument

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

On .net core while trying load my url to XMLDocument i getting that 500 Internal Server Error. While i get datas from same url with HTTPWebRequest it was have same error but after i add

```
request.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
```

That line it was solved my problem. But now i trying get datas with XML But getting that error again. How can i solve it ? Thanks for replies! My codes for XMLDocument :

```
string url = "https://www.antalyaeo.org.tr/tr/nobetci-eczaneler";
            var xml = new XmlDocument(); 

            xml.Load(url);
```

Comment: Download the file and pass the local file to XmlDocument? - eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192993

Comment: @RandRandom i must get datas from url brother. So i cant download and pass it.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about your error? try adding a try-catch block and see more detail.

Comment: As far as I know, the XmlDocument.Load method doesn't contains the property which support modify the Header. The only way is you firstly make request to the target url and then load the response stream in the XML document. Details, you could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7789235/7609093).

Comment: Rand Randoms response seems like the way to go. You're still pulling the xml 'fresh' from that url and you get the chance to insert the header you need to avoid the url giving a 500 response instead of the xml you're looking for.