# asp.net alternate to curl uri

Tags: asp.net, curl

What would be alternative in asp.net for below curl uri

```
curl -u MyUserName:MyPassword "http://api.messaging.staging.voxeo.net/1.0/messaging" -X POST -d "botkey=12345&apimethod=send&msg=My%20test%20message.&user=14075555555&network=SMS&from=14076666666"
```

URI part is easy but how do i add username and password as i need to set some http headers for this like following

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

 $data="botkey=".$botkey."&apimethod=send&msg=".$msg."&userkey=".$userKey."&network=SMS&from=".$from;
 HERE IT IS SETTING USERNAME PASSWORD
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '[Evolution User Name]:[Evolution Password]');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) or [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) classed to interact with other sites. Given your use case seems a little more complicated/specific I would recommend `HttpWebRequest`.

You can use the `Credentials` property to assign your Username/Password credentials and the `Header` property to add your custom headers.

[This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699938/how-to-download-the-file-using-httpwebrequest-and-httpwebresponse-classcookies) has sample code. Do note that you should dispose of your HttpRequest objects correctly as well as they access unmanaged resources.