# Execute curl request in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, curl

I have read some other posts on Stack but I can't get this to work. It works fine on my when I run the curl in php code on my windows machine but when I convert it to asp.net it's not working

```
<%
Dim gv_rand_no, gv_ch, gv_email_id, gv__GET()

gv_rand_no  = rand(0,99)
gv_ch  = rand(0,99)
gv_email_id  = gv__GET("email")

string url = "http://api.mycompany.com/post-api.php";
string data = "{\"id\":9970080, \"email\":\"gv_email_id\",\"method\":2,\"action_id\":110,\"random_number\":\"gv_rand_no\"}";


WebRequest myReq = WebRequest.Create(url);
myReq.Method = "POST";
myReq.ContentLength = data.Length;
myReq.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";

using (Stream ds = myReq.GetRequestStream())
{
  ds.Write(enc.GetBytes(data), 0, data.Length); 
}

WebResponse wr = myReq.GetResponse();
Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(content);
Console.ReadLine();
%>
```

I am not familiar with ASP.net. i have converted code using of online code convertor

http://www.me-u.com/php-asp

please help me on this

Comment: Mentioning `not working` is not a very good attempt to ask a question. We are not magician here! Please be intuitive if you really want an answer here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp.net alternate to curl uri](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315772/asp-net-alternate-to-curl-uri)