# Download file using System.Net.WebClient for pages with form based logins

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to download a file from a microsoft site, that uses form based logins (microsoft account). How can I do that using WebClient ?
The link is something like "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/ ....."
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set credentials to the `WebRequest` as follows. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699938/how-to-download-the-file-using-httpwebrequest-and-httpwebresponse-classcookies) explains how to download the file.

```
// Create a request for the specified remote file name
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(remoteFilename);
if (request != null)
{
    string username = "username";
    string password = "password";
    request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
}
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for helping me, but the file keeps with the message : <html><head><noscript>JavaScript required to sign in<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=https://login.live.com/jsDisabled.srf"