# Download CSV file with WebClient in C# but the size of file is less than when download with browser

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I have a link that returns a CSV file. When I open it in a browser (Chrome, Firefox,...) the size of file that's downloaded is 86 KB, but when I want to download it with the code below, the size is just 25 KB and when I open the downloaded file it doesn't have correct data (means no columns and can't read data)

**You can try it in browser and code**

http://tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/Export-txt.aspx?t=i&a=1&b=0&i=43283802997035462

```
string url = "http://tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/Export-txt.aspx?t=i&a=1&b=0&i=43283802997035462";
 WebClient wc = new WebClient();
 wc.DownloadFile(url, "111.csv");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webClient is returning you zip file instead of plain text /csv file
I changed wc output file extension to zip and it is working...
zip will contain file that you specified in argument

[screenshot from RestClient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thMpp.png)

Comment: You mean I save file as .zip? if yes and then how to open it (extract it ?)

Comment: this should help you out... https://stackoverflow.com/a/14635025/9356147

Answer (score 0):

As Akshay Sandhu pointed out the downloaded file is compressed with the gzip encoding and that is why it appears as corrupted when trying to open it as a csv.
To download the file and automatically decode it please refer to these two SO answers.
First download the file using the HttpWebRequest class instead of the WebClient class as done here:

[How to Download the File using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse class(Cookies,Credentials,etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699938/how-to-download-the-file-using-httpwebrequest-and-httpwebresponse-classcookies)

Then make sure the file is automatically decompressed. Check this out

[Automatically decompress gzip response via WebClient.DownloadData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973208/automatically-decompress-gzip-response-via-webclient-downloaddata)

Here is the working code:

```
string url = "http://tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/Export-txt.aspx?t=i&a=1&b=0&i=43283802997035462";
string path = "111.csv";

using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;

    const int BUFFER_SIZE = 16 * 1024;
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int bytesRead;
            do
            {
                bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            } while (bytesRead > 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decompress the gzip, before you read it to file.

```
var url = new Uri("http://tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/Export-txt.aspx?t=i&a=1&b=0&i=43283802997035462");
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
var fileName = "111.csv";

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
using (Stream s = File.Create(Path.Combine(path, fileName)))
using (GZipStream gs = new GZipStream(wc.OpenRead(url), CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    //Saves to C:\Users\[YourUser]\Desktop\111.csv
    gs.CopyTo(s);
}
```